# I am not able to install svnnotify

Tags: macos, perl, svn-notify

I tried to install svnnotify(SVN-NOTIFY-2.8.4) and when I tried to execute the svnnotify which was saved in the bin of the download folder. I got the below response:

```
Can't locate SVN/Notify.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at /Users/bertils/Downloads/SVN-Notify-2.84/bin/svnnotify line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/bertils/Downloads/SVN-Notify-2.84/bin/svnnotify line 4.
```

Comment: Any one to help me fix this issue?

Comment: You say you tried to install it, but here you're talking about running it from the downloads folder. What steps did you take to install the module?

Comment: am using mac, and searched for svnnotify, but it was nowhere to be found. Then I downloaded SVN-NOTIFY-2.8.4 to my downloads, went to the bin folder and tried to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You skipped the install step.

Check the `README.md` file in the unzipped module, but basically you'll want to run:

```
perl Build.pl
```

if you're warned about missing dependencies, then (as suggested by the last command), install those. You probably want to do that as root:

```
sudo ./Build installdeps
```

next (again, from the README)

```
./Build 
./Build test
```

if those steps went well, install (as root):

```
sudo ./Build install
```

`svnnotify` should now be in your path, ready to run.